# Magento store wise order, customers and login

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, multistore, model, store-view

I am fully aware of Magento multi-store, multi-website functionality.  what I am looking for is store wise admin.  It means someone with admin credential can log in into my store and he can see only orders and customers of that stores.

For example:
There is one **website A** which have stores  **store1**, **store2** and **store 3**.

store1, store2 and store 3 have different admin login credentials.  if I login in **store 1** I can see orders of that store, customers and pages. I can not see the customers and order of **store 2** and **store 3**.

Need help how to manage this.  is it possible with Magento? is there any module for that?

Comment: This extension might be useful https://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_advanced_permissions.html

Comment: Or this is free https://github.com/magento-hackathon/AdvancedAcl

Comment: Glad that it could help you

Comment: @Sukeshini, any help for Magento2?

Comment: @Teja bhagavan Kollepara : It seems this feature only available in enterprise edition. There are third party modules which might fulfill your requirement. However, they are not available for free. 
https://www.aitoc.com/en/magento_2_advanced_permissions.html , 
https://amasty.com/advanced-permissions-for-magento-2.html